# How to import column names in jupyter notebook, when column names are number (not letter)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have an excel file in which the name of columns are numbers (like: 01_Jan_2019). I could not write this in jupyter and it says:

```
Syntax error: invalid token
```

Does anyone can help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the column name as index instead of property

Both the lines below returns same series

```
data.column_name
data['column_name']
```

So change your statement to

```
 data['01_jan_18']
```